# Getting error while launching the browser in Pytest by passing arguments in command line

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

```
#this is conftest files

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = None


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(request, browser, url):
    global driver
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    elif browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
    elif browser == "edge":
        driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()


# this will get the value of CLI/Hooks
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")
    parser.addoption("--url")


# This will return the browser value to setup method
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser", action='store')


# This will return the url value to setup method
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def url(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--url", action='store')


#This is the file where all xpaths are defined

import time

#defined xpath for all the page element in that page
class ErrorMessage:

    myAccount_xpath = "//span[text()='My Account']"

    registerAccount_xpath = "//a[text()='Register']"

    submit_xpath = "//input[@type='submit']"

    FnameError_Xapth = "//div[text()='First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!']"

    LnameError_Xpath = "//div[text()='Last Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!']"

    EmailError_Xpath = "//div[text()='E-Mail Address does not appear to be valid!']"

    TelError_Xpath = "//div[text()='Telephone must be between 3 and 32 characters!']"

    PwdError_Xpath = "//div[text()='Password must be between 4 and 20 characters!']"


    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver

#Passsing xpath to the method
    def error_name(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.myAccount_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.registerAccount_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.submit_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(2)
        fnerror = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.FnameError_Xapth).text
        assert fnerror == "First Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!"
        lnerror = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.LnameError_Xpath).text
        assert lnerror == "Last Name must be between 1 and 32 characters!"
        emailerror = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.EmailError_Xpath).text
        assert emailerror == "E-Mail Address does not appear to be valid!"
        telerror = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.TelError_Xpath).text
        assert telerror == "Telephone must be between 3 and 32 characters!"
        pwderror = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.PwdError_Xpath).text
        assert pwderror == "Password must be between 4 and 20 characters!"
```

#This files where test case is defined

```
import pytest

from pages.loginfail import ErrorMessage


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class LoginFail:

    def __init__(self):
        self.error = None
```

#Imported mehthod from xpath class to run a test cases

```
    # @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def test_ra_003(self):
        self.error = ErrorMessage(self.driver)
        self.error.error_name()




#I am passing below codes in command line 
python -m pytest -m test_LoginFail.py --browser firefox --url "https://demo.opencart.com/"


And getting below errors while executing
#ERROR: usage: __main__.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
#__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --browser --url https://demo.opencart.com/
  #inifile: None
  #rootdir: F:\PycharmPrjects\POMSelenium\testscripts
```

same codes will work fine if i use single browser to launch. Please help me to debug this issue. I tried google but I did not get any solution to this. While passing the --browser and --url arguments i am getting error. Not getting what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same problem in selenium 4.2.0, pytest 7.1.2

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        print("Firefox driver")
    elif browser_name == "IE":
        print("IE driver")
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

[picture of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IChOB.png)

OUTPUT:

```
(venv) (base) sankalp@Sankalps-MacBook-Air tests % py.test --browser_name = chrome      
============================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/sankalp/PycharmProjects/PythonSelFramework/tests
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                             

============================================================================ no tests ran in 0.00s ============================================================================
ERROR: file or directory not found: chrome
```

Comment: add file name properly. Ex:  in test package you need to mention file name as test, Class name should start with Test_Case and test items should start with test_

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32022868)